# How to fetch data from db with observables

Tags: typescript, angular

I am trying to get the  records  from  my  db, i wrote the  observables and with the following  code  i am  not  getting  any  records.Can  someone please suggest help.

my  component,

```
  import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
  import {Component} from '@angular/core';
  import {Http, Response, Headers} from '@angular/http';
  import {Observable} from 'rxjs/Observable';
  import { IDetails } from './details';
 @Component({

    templateUrl: './components/search/search.html',

 })
 @Injectable()
 export class Search {

    details:IDetails[];

      constructor(public http: Http) {
         this.http = http;
       }

     submit(id):any{


      var headers = new Headers();
        var id  = localStorage.getItem('social_id')
       headers.append('Content-Type','application/x-www-form-urlencoded')
      this.http.get('http://localhost/a2server/index.php/profile/search/'+id,{headers:headers})
        .subscribe(
         response => { <IDetails[]> response.json(); })
}
     }
```

I am trying to get the  records  from  my  db, i wrote the  observables and with the following  code  i am  not  getting  any  records.Can  someone please suggest help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**UPDATE**

In your comment to my answer, I believe you ask what is the reason to use an Observable. In your specific code there isn't much of a reason to use one besides the fact that the Http object is designed to return Observables. I should point out though that you are going about your Http call not in the best way when it comes to good practices.

Your Http call should really be in a Service instead of directly inside your Component. The Component should Subscribe to the Observable in your service. Here is a [Plunker](https://plnkr.co/edit/9NfnBSgnqP3gmOO9vwSW?p=info) that is demonstrating how to leverage an Observable with a Service.

```
export class ComponentOne{
  private _videoID:number;
  private _searchedItem:IVideo;
  constructor(private _videoService:VideoService){
    this._videoID = 0;
    this._searchedItem = {};
  }

  componentClick():void{
    this._videoService.getVideo(this._videoID).subscribe((data: IVideo) => {
    console.log(data);
    });
  }
}
```

Here is a really good [tutorial](https://coryrylan.com/blog/angular-2-observable-data-services) that I used to become familiar in how to leverage Observables.

---

Looks like you're just forgetting to set your "details" variable to the return results. I think you just need to adjust your subscribe function to look like this(this assumes your php call is working).

```
response => { this.details = <IDetails[]> response.json(); })
```

Comment: Thank you Dan,it worked then what is the purpose of using the step   Observable<IDetails[]>

Comment: @nlr_p - I think you were asking in the comment why the need for an Observable. I have updated the answer to reflect that.